# Can't show the wireframe effect appropriately on some parts of my .obj in three.js

Tags: javascript, object, three.js

I've tried wireframe, it works fairly well on the objects in examples, but for some parts of it, looks like flashing lines as i shown in the image....

my code:

```
            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                        child.material.wireframe = true;

                    }

                } );
```

thanks!

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be applying any material/s to the object.

Comment: post some images, impossible to tell what your problem may be from provided information. What is weird about them, since that implies that they might be working?

Comment: thanks so much for your reply, I fairly figure out the original question, the reason is a bit silly, just because the obj have too much meshs, so I couldn't see the wireframe effect appropriately. But I still have a little question, the wireframe can work on the example obj, but for some part (i shown in the image) it looks like flashing lines......?

Comment: Which example are you using? "Flashing" can be caused by a number of things, but my initial guess would be two meshes in the same location are causing z-fighting.